# javascript - Calculate sum between array of objects base on key and return same array but change the sum

Tags: javascript

Made sample array -

```
 const arr = [
     {
        id: '319922',
        date: '08/03/2021',
        quantity: 180,
      },
      {
        id: '319923',
        date: '08/03/2021',
        quantity: 20,
      },
      {
        id: '319924',
        date: '08/04/2021',
        quantity: 150,
      },
      {
        id: '319925',
        date: '08/04/2021',
        quantity: 30,
      } 
    ]
```

Wanted result -

```
    {
    id: '319922',
    date: '08/03/2021',
    quantity: 200,
  },
  {
    id: '319923',
    date: '08/03/2021',
    quantity: 200,
  },
  {
    id: '319924',
    date: '08/04/2021',
    quantity: 180,
  },
  {
    id: '319925',
    date: '08/04/2021',
    quantity: 180,
  }
```

The key is date
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: which field is `key` in your given data? date?

Comment: @ParthPatel yes

Comment: Please add your try and the issues you're having. Stack Overflow has a minimum character requirement when posting questions for a reason, please don't try and bypass that by adding dots `.`. Instead, explain your issue and provide details about what you're trying to do along with your attempt and where you're getting stuck. Not adding your attempt or showing research effort isn't a good look as it comes off as asking other people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Create map with total count and date, use map to generate result

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "319922",
    date: "08/03/2021",
    quantity: 180,
  },
  {
    id: "319923",
    date: "08/03/2021",
    quantity: 20,
  },
  {
    id: "319924",
    date: "08/04/2021",
    quantity: 150,
  },
  {
    id: "319925",
    date: "08/04/2021",
    quantity: 30,
  },
];

const map = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.date]) {
    acc[curr.date] += curr.quantity;
  } else {
    acc[curr.date] = curr.quantity;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = arr.map((item) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    quantity: map[item.date],
  };
});

console.log(result);
```